# Best option for check-in/out with small team using Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: version-control, tfs, versioning, dreamweaver, visual-studio-2012

I have a small team of web developers who work together on up to 50 external sites.  I am trying to find a better solution to using Dreamweaver's check-in check-out for managing source. We have just started using Visual Studio 2012 here and there and I am curious if TFS is the way to go for us.  No one here has ever used versioning or any type of source control before, so I am looking for something similar to what they are used to.

If it matters at all, our sites are all hosted on a Windows 2008 R2 server, and largely written in C#.

Comment: If Shakespeare was alive today he would have just said: "To SVN or not to SVN that is the question". Why don't you setup SVN server internally?  There is ton of resources how to setup/maintain and most importantly use SVN.

Comment: Lol.... I suspect he would! I should mention that 99% of the changes that will occur are simply team members updating a .cshtml page and needing to update the 'live' site.   --- if that makes any difference at all.

Comment: TFS is a big jump from check-in/check-out that you see in Dreamweaver.    As far as I recall check-in/check-out was implemented with concept of .lck files and this could be implemented as add-on to VS but would probably take some time. But you can always invest time to teach people TFS (it will take time since no one has used version control) but is doable.

Comment: Yeah I am worried it will freak a couple of them out since they are more web designers than developers/programmers.  Is there a solution for VS that IS similar to the Dreamweaver check in/out feature then?

Comment: If your designers only need basic operations like check in, check out, TFS might be too heavy for them. Did you think of using a hosting version control service with good customer service (such as SourceAnywhere Hosted)? That will simplify the whole process.

Comment: Microsoft offering [TFS Express 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/tfs-express2) for free as long as your team is up to 5 users.

Comment: I've got very bad experiences in using TFS together with web-folks. TFS is more than code-management and if you only want this, than TFS makes them feeling disturbed. The don't like imperative tools :-). We're using other stuff like SVN or Git there - sadly!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think TFS is a good option to consider.  As several people have commented, it will be a jump from what you are your team are used to in Dreamweaver, but I personally feel if you are serious about managing your intellectual property, you will invest in some sort of version control system.  With that said, there will be a learning curve regardless whether you are your team select TFS, SVN, Git, etc.

Assuming you do go with TFS, you do get the added benefit of everything else that comes with TFS - it's not just about version control.  This includes work item tracking, automated builds/deployments, reports, a simple SharePoint site, etc.

With TFS you get the benefit of all of these features, combined into a single product.  You can accomplish a similar setup using open source products as well, but would require you to piece the products together.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the integrated Subversion client in Dreamweaver, which does the basic stuff very nicely and doesn't require the tedious navigation process that will lead to your team bypassing the system. Only problem, DW does not support the latest versions of SVN so you need to pick up an SVN server that is compatible. Try this:

Setting Up Version Control for Dreamweaver CS6 on Windows

1. Any previous attempts to get version control working may well have created some .svn folders and files on your PC. You MUST remove ALL of these  and UNINSTALL ALL OTHER VARIETIES of Subversion software from your PC before you start.
2. Go to the VisualSVN Server website and download an archived standard version of  their software, version 2.1.16 . Don’t be tempted to grab a later version, because this will install SVN 1.7 or 1.8 and neither will work with Dreamweaver.

http://www.visualsvn.com/server/changes/

1. Trying to get DW working direct to a local folder using the file:// protocol probably won’t work and is also known to put data at risk. You need the server. I chose to install the VisualSVN server with the default settings, other than opting to use Windows logins and go with HTTP, not HTTPS. I decided to have the repositories live on an internal SSD drive, but any local drive will do. When creating a folder for your repositories to live in, use a name that is pretty general e.g. ourcorepositories . I used lower case for everything.
2. Right click on ‘Repositories’ to create a new one. Give it a name without any spaces or special characters e.g. mynewprojectrepo and check to ‘Create default structure’ . Before you OK, note the Repository URL and copy it into Notepad or a similar plain text editor so you can refer to it later during 6 below.  It will be something like

   ```
   http://OFFICEDESKTOP/svn/mynewprojectrepo
   ```

Notice that the capitalised part of the URL is the name of your computer. Click OK and you now have a repository for your project.
5.  Boot DW and go to your project. If you don’t have a project yet, create one and stick some dummy files and folders in it. Go to Site menu>>Manage sites… and 2-click your project. Select Version Control.
6.  Set Access to be ‘Subversion’ (no other choices exist), Protocol to be HTTP and for the Server Address enter the name of your computer in lower case e.g.

```
    officedesktop
```

For the Repository Path enter (e.g., using current example from 4. Above)

```
    /svn/mynewprojectrepo
```

The Server Port should be  80   . For the Username enter your Windows user name, in lower case. Enter your Windows password for the Password. This is the name and password combo that you use to log in to your PC . Click the Test button and you should get a success message. If not, the best advice is to delete any .svn files and repositories you have created and start again. Be sure not to add any slashes or omit any; the above works. Before you click Save, click the link to the Adobe Subversion resources and bookmark it in your browser. There is a lot of useful background information there. Click Save, click Done.
7.  Go to your DW project and open up Local View.  All of your site’s  files and folders will have a green + sign beside the icon. Right-click on the site folder and click ‘Version control>>Commit” . It is a very good idea to leave comments whenever you change anything, so leave a Commit Message along the lines of “The initial commit for My New Project” and click to Commit. If you have a lot of files to go to the repository, they’ll take some time to upload. As they upload, the green + signs disappear to show that you local version is in synch with the repo.
8.  Okay, that’s it, you have Version Control in Dreamweaver CS6. It may also work in CS5 and 5.5. Check out those Adobe resources for some good insights on workflow. I can’t help with any other ways to implement version control, but  I can maybe save you time by saying that DW doesn’t integrate with Git and that the basic, but integrated, Subversion client in Dreamweaver is way better than having no version control. For coverage against physical disaster, I’d also add in a scheduled daily backup of your entire repositories folder to some cloud storage.
Apologies for any errors. I’d recheck all of the steps, but A) I think they’ll get you up and running and B) it’s easier to do the install and set up the first time than the second time (all those .svn files and folders to get rid of).